# Getting exception while using NotesCalendar.getNewInvitations

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotus

I am getting exception while invoking NotesCalendar.getNewInvitations method.

```
NotesException: NotesCalendar error: The database handle is NULL
    at lotus.domino.local.NotesCalendar.NgetNewInvitations(Native Method)
    at lotus.domino.local.NotesCalendar.getNewInvitations(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.main(Unknown Source)
```

I am trying to run this code locally to Domino Server.

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends NotesThread {

public static void main(String []args){
    try    
        {        
            NotesThread.sinitThread(); // start thread            
            Session session = NotesFactory.createSession();
            System.out.println("session="+session);
            // (Your code goes here)
            DbDirectory dbdir = session.getDbDirectory("");
            System.out.println("dbdir="+dbdir);
           Database db1= session.getDatabase("server", "Conf");


            NotesCalendar cal = session.getCalendar(db1);


            java.util.Calendar jdt = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            jdt.set(2015, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
            DateTime dt1 = session.createDateTime(jdt);
            DateTime dt2 = session.createDateTime("Yesterday 02");
          //  java.util.Vector invites = cal.getNewInvitations(dt1, dt2);
          //  System.out.println("invites "+invites.size());
            java.util.Vector invites= cal.getEntries(dt1, dt2);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            // Create document to post results
            Document doc = db1.createDocument();
            doc.appendItemValue("Form", "main");
            doc.appendItemValue("subject", "New invitations");
            RichTextItem body = doc.createRichTextItem("body");
            if (invites.size() == 0) body.appendText("No invitations");
            else {
              for (int i = 0; i < invites.size(); i++) {
                  NotesCalendarNotice cale = (NotesCalendarNotice)invites.elementAt(i);
                  body.appendText(cale.read());
               cale.recycle();
                  body.addNewLine();
              }
            }
            doc.save(true, true);
            java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(30);
            invites = cal.getNewInvitations(dt1, cal.getUntilTime());
        } }       
            catch(Exception e)
        {        
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
            finally
        {        
            NotesThread.stermThread(); // must terminate every thread
        }
     }    
}
```

Comment: on which row in the code does your appear? Could you point that out please :-)

Comment: If you are running locally on the server then change "server" to "" on your `session.getDatabase()` call.  Also try using the absolute path name for the DB argument - including the extension on the same call.  You can do it either way. The DB name only implies it will be found in the notes/data directory.  Either way try adding the extension.

Comment: What kind of database is Conf.nsf?  I assume it is based on the ResourceReservation design template.  If that's the case, I cannot reproduce the problem, but I don't think getNewInvitations() makes sense for a reservation database.  It was designed to work on a mail file.  Can you try the same code with a mail file instead?

Comment: @ jyrkim : It is giving error at cal.getNewInvitations(dt1, dt2); line. @ jch : I tried both the ways i.e. giving empty string in server parameter as well as server name.And giving the DB name with .nsf extension. @Dave : Yes it is based on ResourceReservation template but i tries with user's mail file as well but no luck .In your did u done any correction/changes.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is getNewInvitations() doesn't make sense in the context of a resource reservation database.  The method was designed to read unprocessed invitations from a mail file.

However, in the comments you say your code doesn't work for mail files either.  It might be helpful to get something simpler to work and then build on that.  I just tried the following code:

```
        database = session.getDatabase(null, "mail/user.nsf");
        NotesCalendar calendar = session.getCalendar(database);

        // Start date is 01-Jan-2015
        java.util.Calendar start = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        start.set(2015, 0, 1);
        dtStart = session.createDateTime(start);

        // End date is now
        java.util.Calendar end = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        dtEnd = session.createDateTime(end);

        // Get entries on the calendar between start and end
        Vector<?> entries = calendar.getEntries(dtStart, dtEnd);
        System.out.println("Number of entries is " + entries.size());

        // Get invitations from start date (from the Inbox)
        Vector<?> invites = calendar.getNewInvitations(dtStart, calendar.getUntilTime());
        System.out.println("Number of invites is " + invites.size());
```

Everything worked as expected.  Perhaps you could try the above code and see if getNewInvitations() still throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Now i am getting different exception.I am using Domino 9.0.1 .Not sure why it going to lotus.domino.cso package even i am running locally to domino server .NotesException: Not implemented
 at lotus.domino.cso.Base.notImplemented(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.cso.Session.getCalendar(Unknown Source)
 at JavaAgent.main(JavaAgent.java:14)

Comment: @Anil, you must have NCSO.jar on the class path.  That's unusual for a Domino server since Notes.jar is always installed.  I suggest you find and remove NCSO.jar.